# Substring of character to numeric as well as parsing in a join

Tags: sql, join, sas

I am trying to do an inner join in proc sql on two variables that are in two different formats, and one needs to be parsed. For example one variable in one table is `123SampleEv` and the other variable in the other table is `123`. I only need to join on the `123` but I can't figure out how to substring and convert from character to numeric in the same statement. Is that possible?

Comment: @pm-77-1 Why was the SAS tag removed? The question mentions `proc sql`, which is likely for SAS.

Comment: @Nicarus - feel free to roll back

Comment: @PM77-1 I can only edit (which I have done) and wait for peer-review. The problem is that the `SAS` tag was provided, you removed it, then asked to identify the SQL flavor...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

In Oracle you can use the substr() function to get the portion of the string you want and you can do to_number() to convert it to a number.  I'm sure there is a similar way to do it with other database types.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are using SAS, so your solution would be to use the `SUBSTR` function that is available.

Here is how it is used:

```
PROC SQL;

    SELECT SUBSTR('123SampleEv',1,3) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
    /* Outputs '123' */

    SELECT INPUT(SUBSTR('123SampleEv',1,3),3.) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
    /* Outputs 123 */

QUIT;
```

The `SUBSTR` function takes 2 or 3 arguments. In your case, you will use these 3:

```
SUBSTR(
   [value as string],
   [starting position as number], /* (starts with 1, not 0) */
   [length as number] /* how many characters should be returned */
)
```

This is the docs for that function: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212267.htm

Keep in mind that if you are matching or joining on this, you may need to cast to the appropriate type. For instance, you may need to cast this output to `NUMERIC` using `INPUT()` if the other value is of the `NUMERIC` data type.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible - You just need to use the `substr` function in the `on` statement in your join and the `input` function to convert the result of substringing to a numeric value.

```
data short_input;
   input id values $8.;
   datalines;
    123 aaa
    234 bbb
    456 ddd
    ;
run;

data long_input;
   input id $ values $8.;
   datalines;
    123sampleev aaaaaaaa
    345sampleev cccccccc
    456sampleev dddddddd
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    create table joined_inputs as select distinct
        a.*, b.values as long_values
        from short_input as a
        inner join long_input as b
        on a.id = input(substr(b.id, 1, 3), 8.);
quit;
```